# Resolve an instance of a parent per registered instance of a child in Ninject

Tags: ninject

I have an interface `public interface IThing` of which there are multiple implementations:

- `public class Thing1 : IThing`
- `public class Thing2 : IThing`
- `public class Thing3 : IThing`

I also have another class which accepts an instance of `IThing`:

```
public class CallThing
{
    public CallThing(IThing) { ... }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is resolve an instance of `CallThing` per implementation of `IThing` from Ninject:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IThing>().To<Thing1>();
kernel.Bind<IThing>().To<Thing2>();
kernel.Bind<IThing>().To<Thing3>();

kernel.Bind<CallThing>().ToSelf();

var callThings = kernel.GetAll<CallThing>();
```

At the moment, I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IThing
More than one matching bindings are available.
Matching bindings:
  1) binding from IThing to Thing1
  2) binding from IThing to Thing2
  3) binding from IThing to Thing3
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IThing into parameter thing of constructor of type
CallThing
  1) Request for CallThing

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IThing only once.
```

How do I configure Ninject to get the result I want?

Comment: Please update your question and show your actual use case. I know you deliberately made the question more general/abstract, but in the context of dependency injection, more details is usually better, because the answer is dependent on the context. Please show the names of the classes and describe their function or show their behavior.

Comment: @Steven it doesn't make any difference what the implementations do, all I want is `n` instances of `CallThing` where each receives an instance of each registered `IThing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a case which ninject supports.
You'll have to create one `CallThing` per `IThing` yourself (meaning: using a factory, for exmaple a Ninject.Extensions.Factory Func-Factory or interface factory).

You could also register an `IProvider` to do this for you, or a collection type to be constructed like that, beware however, that ninjects multi-injection feature supersedes any registrations for collections which are multi-injected. For example:

```
Bind<string[]>().ToConstant(new[] { "Foo", "bar" });
```

does *not* work as expected.

What you can do, however, is:

```
kernel.Bind<IReadOnlyCollection<CallThing>>()
      .ToMethod(ctx => 
          ctx.Kernel.GetAll<IThing>()
                    .Select(t => CreateCallThingPerThing(ctx.Kernel, t))
                    .ToList());

public static CallThing CreateCallThingPerThing(
    IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot,
    IThing thing)
{
    var parameter = new TypeMatchingConstructorArgument(
                            typeof(IThing),
                            (ctx, target) => thing);
    return resolutionRoot.Get<CallThing>(parameter);
}
```

And then inject `IReadOnlyCollection<CallThing>`.
This works because ninject's multi-injection feature does not support `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, the `IReadOnlyCollection` approach worked fine